# Unable to write policy file in vault test container

Tags: spring-boot, vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I'm trying to associate a policy file in my vault test container. But It is giving me an error.

Below is the command I'm running.

```
Container.ExecResult result = vaultContainer.execInContainer("vault", "policy", "write", "admin", "- <<EOF\n" +
"path \"secret/*\" {\n" +
"  capabilities = [ \"read\" ]\n" +
"}\n" +
"EOF");
```

Error:

```
Container.ExecResult(exitCode=2, stdout=, stderr=Error opening policy file: open - <<EOF
path "secret/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]
}
EOF: no such file or directory
)
```

And policy is not getting written in the vault container. Any help would be greatly apprecited.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run the command with the following steps:

1. Create a policy file in the resources folder.
2. Map this file `.withClasspathResourceMapping("policy.hcl", "/opt/policy.hcl", BindMode.READ_ONLY);`.
3. Run the command to create policy. `vaultContainer.execInContainer("vault", "policy", "write", "full_access","/opt/policy.hcl")`